# imbalanced dataset with Keras deep learning

Tags: python, keras, confusion-matrix, imbalanced-data

I have a datasets that looks like this:  Training (Class 0: 471, Class 1: 986) Testing (Class 0: 177, Class 1: 246.
I split my data as 80% for training and 20% for validation.
I know that is an imbalanced dataset, and I have tried Class_weight but the problem remains.
I have retrained my Baseline CNN and I always have a result like as attached in the picture.
Could someone help me?
[image: My Result after training]

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem while classifying events in 5 imbalanced categories. I found this loss function that implement a weighted categorical cross-entropy: https://gist.github.com/noparade/aaa8584e6e90ad64936e333e4e08ca5f
Combined with the Nadam optimizer, it allowed me to get over 95% true positive for all my categories.